# cannot find device "eth0" when trying to add secondary ip to AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-ip

I have followed a youtube video on creating an ec2 and then adding two elastic ip addresses to the instance. However when I ssh into the ubuntu server to add the new secondary ip I get an error that says

```
cannot find device "eth0"
```

when I run the below command

```
sudo ip addr add 172.31.32.210/20 dev eth0
```

Note I released that ip so its not my ip address anymore but you can see the command I am using. What would cause this error and how to resolve?

If I run a ip link command I get the below:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ens5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 0e:e4:6d:b4:d6:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Try switching your dev argument to ens5 in your `ip addr add` command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your network interface is named `ens5`, not `eth0`. You should use the correct interface name in your commands. Having interfaces *actually* named `eth0` after the system is booted has been deprecated for years, and these days you should treat it as an example only, especially when using outdated tutorials.

Comment: Thank you !! So I should do a ip link anytime I setup an ec2 to get what the network interface is labeled as. I think in the ec2 console when creating an instance the network interface section lists ent0 in the default row.

Comment: The device name _should_ always be the same for any particular combination of Linux distro and EC2 instance type (e.g. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on t2.medium). But checking it is always a good idea.